# trying to link route 53 to a cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

Here's my CloudFront distribution:

[image]

When I try to get Route 53 to route to that CloudFront distribution, per the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html, it can't find it:

[image]

One thing I note is that Route 53 wants to know the region that my CloudFront distribution is in, however, as per my first screenshot, the CloudFront distribution is not in a region. Or rather, it's in the Global region.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try pasting in the endpoint address for your distribution. It will be something like https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net